# Is there any way to hide window frame of the running 3rd part application?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I have exe application which is not mine. The application has window and inside the window displayes pictures and another data content. I would like to make the application fullscreened or at least hide the frame of the application or (if it is possible) wrap the content of the application into the mine own form which will be fullscreened.

Is it possible to:
* make 3rd part application fullscreened
* Hide window frame of the application
* embed the application into the my onf winform application

Comment: `Is it possible to: * make 3rd part application fullscreened * Hide window frame of the application` Yes, it is.

Comment: Is there any example howto do this?

Comment: There may be. I only know it's possible, nothing more. Sorry.